# Set _Id as update key in logstash elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Im having an index as below:

```
{
"_index": "mydata",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "PuhnbG0B1IIlyY9-ArdR",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"age": 9,
"@version": "1",
"updated_on": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"id": 4,
"name": "Emma",
"@timestamp": "2019-09-26T07:09:11.947Z"
}
```

So my logstash conf for updaing data is input {

```
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "***"
        jdbc_driver_class =>  "***"
    jdbc_driver_library => "***"
        jdbc_user => ***
        statement => "SELECT * from agedata WHERE updated_on > :sql_last_value ORDER BY updated_on"
    use_column_value =>true
        tracking_column =>updated_on
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    }
}
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "mydata" 
        action => update
            document_id => "{_id}"
            doc_as_upsert =>true}
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
```

So, when i run this after any updation in the same row, my expected output is to update the existing _id values for any changes i made in that row.
But my Elasticsearch is indexing it as a new row where my _id is considered as a string.

```
"_index": "agesep",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": ***"%{_id}"***
```

The duplicate occurs when i use document_id => "%{id}"  as:
actual:

```
         {
"_index": "mydata",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "BuilbG0B1IIlyY9-4P7t",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"id": 1,
"age": 13,
"name": "Greg",
"updated_on": "2019-09-26T08:11:00.000Z",
"@timestamp": "2019-09-26T08:17:52.974Z",
"@version": "1"
}
}
```

duplicate:

```
{
"_index": "mydata",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"age": 56,
"@version": "1",
"id": 1,
"name": "Greg",
"updated_on": "2019-09-26T08:18:00.000Z",
"@timestamp": "2019-09-26T08:20:14.561Z"
}
```

How do i get it to consider the existing _id and not create a duplicate value when i make updates in ES?
My expectation is to update data in the index based on the _id, and not create a new row of update.

Comment: You're missing a `%` in `"{_id}"`. Also have you tried `%{id}` instead of `%{_id}`

Comment: @Val, I tried %{id}, which is a column in my table, but it still was creating a new _id value for every update, creating a new row as duplicate for IDs.

Comment: @Val, sorry, it woked the first time, but now its again `
"_index": "agesep",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "%{_id}",`, im not sure why

Comment: See my answer, you need to use `id` not `_id`. There's no `_id` field coming from your DB

Comment: @val, but if i use id, then the value is still coming as a duplicate new row, not as a update on the existing index.

Comment: Can you show two duplicate rows?

Comment: Well, your index probably has a lot of documents from your initial tries (see the ids: `PuhnbG0B1IIlyY9-ArdR` vs `4`). I suggest you delete it and rerun everything from the beginning so that all ids are correct right from the start.

Comment: But, when im looking at a large data set, it wont be easy to clear the index all the time @val

Comment: Your index contains garbage data... Delete `~/.logstash_jdbc_last_run` and start over again

Comment: Alright let me try that. is that a file im looking at? @Val

Comment: Yes, that's the file Logstash uses to store the `sql_last_value` for the next run. Just delete it, delete your `agesep` index and restart Logstash

Comment: @val, I tried an entire new index with the same, but unfortunately, it still creates the same issue.a duplicate is created as a new row. The first _id that gets created is not proper. I couldnt find ~/.logstash_jdbc_last_run in my logstash as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199998/discussion-between-spishere-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `id` instead of `_id`

```
        document_id => "%{id}"
```