# push data from the last updated_on date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

So im using the below query in my jdbc logstash input.

```
statement => "SELECT * from mydata WHERE updated_on > :sql_last_value  ORDER BY updated_on"
use_column_value =>true
tracking_column =>updated_on
tracking_column_type => "@timestamp"
```

or

```
statement => "SELECT * from mydata WHERE  :sql_last_value > updated_on ORDER BY updated_on"
use_column_value =>true
tracking_column =>updated_on
tracking_column_type => "@timestamp"
```

here, my :sql_last value is considered as the last run time of the configuration file.
example:

```
"updated_on": "2019-09-26T08:11:00.000Z",
"@timestamp": "2019-09-26T08:17:52.974Z"
```

here my sql_last_value corresponds to @timestamp,
I want it to consider updated_on instead.

How do i change it to consider the last updated_on date instead of execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is [your current configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111721/set-id-as-update-key-in-logstash-elasticsearch):

```
    statement => "SELECT * from agedata WHERE updated_on > :sql_last_value ORDER BY updated_on"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => updated_on
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
```

What it says is basically that the `sql_last_value` variable will store/remember the last value of the `updated_on` column from the last run since `use_column_value` is `true` (**not the last run time value** as you suggest or else `use_column_value` would be `false`).

So your configuration is already doing what you expect.

Comment: I am already using the mentioned. Apologies, i did not put it on the question. but its still the same. it always takes the execution time. @val

Comment: How do you know that? do you see the queries being run?

Comment: when i execute logstash -f myconffile.conf, it shows, `[2019-09-26T11:51:22,089][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc ] (0.087419s) SELECT * from agedata WHERE updated_on > '2019-09-26T11:43:00.000' ORDER BY updated_on` where the timestamp mentioned is actually my last run time, thats how i found out. in place of sql_last_value, the timestamp is mentioned. @val

Comment: What do you see in `c:/Users/<username>/.logstash_jdbc_last_run` ?

Comment: What is the latest `updated_on` value after the query has run?

Comment: it shows the latest updated_on date., i might be making a mistake here, i can check on it! what you pointed out is right, i can see that!